# How to set up cocoahttpserver with configure MIME type

Tags: ios5, ios6, mime-types, profile, cocoahttpserver

This question need a lot background on apple's air play profile configure.

Firstly, I set up the web server in the iOS app with cocoahttpserver, and want to provide the access to .mobileconfig, but this need set up the MIME type as application/x-apple-aspen-config. For PHP setup, here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426408/open-a-configuration-profile-through-app)

But I am setting up the web server in the iOS app with cocoahttpserver, and I am not familiar with such configuration. So question here to seek professional suggest for this.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to inherit one of HTTPResponse classes and ovverride httpHeaders method.

Take a look at this question to see how it's done:
[Change Download File Name in Cocoahttpserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780368/change-download-file-name-in-cocoahttpserver)

The only different with that question that you have to setup "Content-Type" header instead of "Content-Disposition"